# Ошибка MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Недавно пришлось работать с  MySQL. Написал такую строку на php:

```
$query = "SELECT 'catalog' FROM $moduls WHERE posit = 'head'";
```

После запроса выдает:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE posit = 'head'' at line 1

Чувствую, что проблема с кавычками, подскажите, как именно надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

название таблицы в MySQL (про отсальные БД не уверен) берется не в одинарные кавычки, а в апостраф который на ё русском. А в кавычках - это строка

```
$query = "SELECT `catalog` FROM ".$moduls." WHERE posit = 'head'";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "SELECT catalog FROM ".$moduls." WHERE posit = 'head'";
```